# remove permanently a commit on bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket, repo, bfg-repo-cleaner

I'm trying to remove usernames from the bitbucket repositories for security reasons

I cloned the repo using --mirror, did the following command bfg --replace-text username.txt , changed the directory to the repo ran this command git reflog expire --expire=now --all && git gc --prune=now --aggressive and git push.

The result was as expected but when searching for the old commit ID I can still see it, username is in clear text and have this error message: "This commit is unreachable from any branch or tag in this repository. It may be from a fork outside of this repository."

Something that I noticed is that the commit ID was replaced in the history but having said that, when you search for the old commit ID I still can see it.

I would like this commit to be removed for good, is there a way to do this please?

Edit: Just a side note, there are multiple commits right after the commit that I would like to remove

Answer (score 1):

To solve this issue I did the same procedure as per description, then opened a ticket with the repository provider, which in return they triggered a gc (garbage cleanup) on the repository and once that is done the commit will no longer be there.

Comment: The most important thing is to revoke whatever password, token, etc. was accidentally exposed. That's the only really secure solution.